# Android app that integrates Baidu Map Navigation failed on BaiduNaviManager init

Tags: android, baidu, baidu-map

To integrate Baidu Map Navigation into one of my Android apps, I followed the implementation in the Baidu Map Navigation officail demo. However, my app fails at `BaiduNaviManager.getInstance().init`. I checked Logcat and saw the exception pasted below:

```
10-29 17:56:12.793 13154 13154 W System.err: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-29 17:56:12.794 13154 13154 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-29 17:56:12.794 13154 13154 W System.err:    at com.baidu.navisdk.adapter.base.BaiduNaviSDKProxy.init(BaiduNaviSDKProxy.java:128)
10-29 17:56:12.794 13154 13154 W System.err:    at com.baidu.navisdk.adapter.BaiduNaviManager.init(BaiduNaviManager.java:237)
10-29 17:56:12.794 13154 13154 W System.err:    at com.xxx.yyy.LocalMainActivity.initNavi(LocalMainActivity.java:768)
10-29 17:56:12.794 13154 13154 W System.err:    at com.xxx.yyy.LocalMainActivity.onCreate(LocalMainActivity.java:216)
10-29 17:56:12.794 13154 13154 W System.err:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
10-29 17:56:12.794 13154 13154 W System.err:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
10-29 17:56:12.794 13154 13154 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
10-29 17:56:12.794 13154 13154 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
10-29 17:56:12.794 13154 13154 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
10-29 17:56:12.794 13154 13154 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
10-29 17:56:12.794 13154 13154 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-29 17:56:12.794 13154 13154 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-29 17:56:12.794 13154 13154 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
10-29 17:56:12.794 13154 13154 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-29 17:56:12.794 13154 13154 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
10-29 17:56:12.794 13154 13154 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
10-29 17:56:12.794 13154 13154 W System.err: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/data/user/0/com.xxx.yyy/lib/libcrypto.so" not found
10-29 17:56:12.795 13154 13154 W System.err:    at java.lang.Runtime.load(Runtime.java:332)
10-29 17:56:12.795 13154 13154 W System.err:    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1069)
10-29 17:56:12.795 13154 13154 W System.err:    at com.baidu.navisdk.adapter.impl.BaiduNaviManager.loadNativeLibrary(BaiduNaviManager.java:312)
10-29 17:56:12.797 13154 13154 W System.err:    at com.baidu.navisdk.adapter.impl.BaiduNaviManager.loadBaiduNaviNativeLibrary(BaiduNaviManager.java:294)
10-29 17:56:12.797 13154 13154 W System.err:    at com.baidu.navisdk.adapter.impl.BaiduNaviManager.init(BaiduNaviManager.java:694)
10-29 17:56:12.797 13154 13154 W System.err:    at com.baidu.navisdk.adapter.impl.BaiduNaviSDKStub.init(BaiduNaviSDKStub.java:399)
```

I followed Baidu's instruction, downloaded the Baidu LBS Android SDK, and added them into the app. The complained `libcrypto.so` is also in `app\src\main\jniLibs\armeabi\`. Other Baidu Map SDK such as Geolocation/Map works fine in my app. Not sure what the root cause is here.

Comment: You can check [androidsdk/guide/create-project/androidstudio](http://lbsyun.baidu.com/index.php?title=androidsdk/guide/create-project/androidstudio) in your SDK document .And check you `.so` file .

Comment: @KeLiuyue thanks for your answer. I had checked those many times and also compared my project structure with those demos. No any clue.

Answer (score 0):

After I created a `armeabi-v7a` directory under `jniLibs` and copied the same `.so` files from `armeabi`, the issue is gone.